# Issue deserializing checkpoint info restarting JSR352 Job - ClassNotFoundException: [B

Tags: java, exception, websphere-liberty, jsr352

I have a partitioned job that reads from and writes to a DB. I have a chunking size of 10. If a partition fails and i want the restart to happen from the last commit, I have overwritten the checkpointinfo method and wrote my logic according to my application requirement. whenever i try to restart the failed job, i am getting an exception that there is failure in Read-Process-Write Loop

Here is the exception logs:

```
[3/1/18 19:18:09:004 IST] [process partition0] com.ibm.ws.batch.JobLogger                                     CWWKY0030I: An exception occurred while running the step process.
com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: Failure in Read-Process-Write Loop
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeChunk(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:704)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeCoreStep(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.BaseStepControllerImpl.execute(BaseStepControllerImpl.java:293)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ExecutionTransitioner.doExecutionLoop(ExecutionTransitioner.java:118)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.executeCoreTransitionLoop(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.executeWorkUnit(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:155)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl$AbstractControllerHelper.runExecutionOnThread(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:480)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.runExecutionOnThread(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:89)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.util.BatchWorkUnit.run(BatchWorkUnit.java:117)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [B
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.util.TCCLObjectInputStream.resolveClass(TCCLObjectInputStream.java:40)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1671)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$300(ObjectInputStream.java:208)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2182)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:543)
    at java.math.BigInteger.readObject(BigInteger.java:4406)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at java.util.HashMap.readObject(HashMap.java:1404)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.persistence.CheckpointData.<init>(CheckpointData.java:47)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.persistence.jpa.StepThreadInstanceEntity.getCheckpointData(StepThreadInstanceEntity.java:131)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.openReaderAndWriter(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:935)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeChunk(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:599)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [B
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.findClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader.findClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass0(UnifiedClassLoader.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader$Delegation.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.UnifiedClassLoader.loadClass(UnifiedClassLoader.java:102)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.ThreadContextClassLoader.loadClass(ThreadContextClassLoader.java:136)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.util.TCCLObjectInputStream.resolveClass(TCCLObjectInputStream.java:38)
    ... 57 more

[3/1/18 19:18:09:005 IST] [process partition0] com.ibm.ws.batch.JobLogger                                     CWWKY0014W: Partition 0 failed with batch status FAILED and exit status null for step process for job instance 105,001 and job execution 105,008.
[3/1/18 19:18:15:588 IST] [process partition0] com.ibm.ws.batch.JobLogger
```

Here are my code snippet

### Item Reader

```
@Override   
public Serializable checkpointInfo() throws Exception {
        Checkpoint checkpoint=new Checkpoint(); 
            for (CheckpointProperty prop:dbOp.getCheckpointInfo().getProperty()) {
                final Object result = ExprUtils.evaluate(newProps,prop.getCheckpointValue().toString());
                checkpoint.addCheckPoint(prop.getName(), result);           }           return checkpoint;
            }
```

### Item writer

```
@Override
    public Serializable checkpointInfo() throws Exception {
            final Properties checkpointInfo = new Properties();
            for (String key : checkpointProps.stringPropertyNames()) {
                final String expr = checkpointProps.getProperty(key);
                final Object result = ExprUtils.evaluate(dataMap, expr);
                checkpointInfo.setProperty(key, result.toString());
            }
            return checkpointInfo;
    }


Checkpoint class
----------------------
public class Checkpoint implements Serializable {
private HashMap<String, Object> checkpoints = new HashMap();

public void reset() {
    this.checkpoints.clear();
}

public void addCheckPoint(String stream, Object position) {
    this.checkpoints.put(stream, position);
}

public Object get(String stream) {
    return this.checkpoints.get(stream);
}

public HashMap<String, Object> getCheckpoints() {
    return this.checkpoints;
}
```

}

Comment: This is a failure deserializing the checkpoint from the previous execution.   What types of objects are your `ItemReader` and `ItemWriter`  `checkpointInfo()` methods returning?    Maybe show a code snippet?

Comment: The check point info method will return a pojo object which has some variables inside in it.. when I try to restart the job for the same instance.. the partition methods are returning the expected value and after the completion of partition methods it calls a constructor of the reader class which implements itemreader and it throws the above exception before it go to open method.. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Can you share snippets of your `ItemReader` and `ItemWriter` `checkpointInfo()` methods plus the class defs of the POJOs that they are returning?  The fact that this is a partitioned step shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the BigInteger Datatype used in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Liberty.  Opened [issue #2792](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/2792).

I think it will happen with any array type, and that you could workaround by using an **ArrayList** in place of an array.

**UPDATE**: A fix for this issue was delivered in 18.0.0.2.